# Scrapy ignoring start page and continuing to next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapy spider that im trying to do pagination but everytime i start the crawling process, it seems to be skipping the start page which is page 1 and going to page 2 right away

```
class IT(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'IT'

allowed_domains = ["jobscentral.com.sg"]
start_urls = [
    'https://jobscentral.com.sg/jobs-accounting',
]

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=("jobscentral.com.sg", ),
                     restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="page-item"]/a[@aria-label="Next"]',)), 
                     callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        )

def parse_item(self, response):
    self.logger.info("Response %d for %r" % (response.status, response.url))
    #self.logger.info("base url %s", get_base_url(response))
    items = []
    self.logger.info("Visited Outer Link %s", response.url)

    for loop in response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-11"]'):
        item = JobsItems()
        t = loop.xpath('./div[@class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 px-0"]/div[@class="posted-date text-muted hidden-sm-down"]//text()').extract()[1].strip()

.... 
more codes here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct because when you use `start_urls` the response goes to the `parse` method the first time. This method is defined by the `CrawlSpider` internally to execute the crawling rules. So if you need to process the response from the first response also. You can use something like below

```
class IT(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'IT'

    allowed_domains = ["jobscentral.com.sg"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://jobscentral.com.sg/jobs-accounting',
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=("jobscentral.com.sg", ), restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="page-item"]/a[@aria-label="Next"]',)), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    first_response = True

    def parse(self, response):
        if self.first_response = True:
            # use it or pass it to some other function
            for r in parse_item(response):
                yield r
           self.first_response = False

        # Pass the response to crawlspider 
        for r in super(IT, self).parse(response)
            yield r


    def parse_item(self, response):

        self.logger.info("Response %d for %r" % (response.status, response.url))
```